# How to include variables from roles (vars) directory ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have my ansible playbook which basically create a new Virtual machine from template in esxi what , i have to convert the playbook into roles. I am new to ansible so i don't know how to call my hard coded variables from roles(install)->vars directory .

This is my playbook

```
---
# create a new VM from a template

- name: VM from template
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: vcenter-app
    vcenter_user: john@doe
    vcenter_pass: blabla6
    esxhost: esx-4.cbalo.fr
    datastore: VM-PROD-02-NORMAL
    vmtemplate: Centos7-template
    name: "newvm2"
    notes: Ansible Test
    dumpfacts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Create VM from template
      vmware_guest:
        validate_certs: False
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        esxi_hostname: "{{ esxhost }}"
        datacenter: CD06
        folder: Test
        name: "{{ name }}"
        template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
        hardware:
          memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory | default(1024) }}"
        wait_for_ip_address: True
        state: present
      register: newvm2
```

I have divide this into my role(install)->tasks->main.yml like this

```
---
- name: Create VM from template
              vmware_guest:
                validate_certs: False
                hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
                username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
                password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
                esxi_hostname: "{{ esxhost }}"
                datacenter: CD06
                folder: Test
                name: "{{ name }}"
                template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
                hardware:
                  memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory | default(1024) }}"
                wait_for_ip_address: True
                state: present
              register: newvm2
```

Then in my main directory i create new file `run.yml` and include my role

```
---
    # create a new VM from a template
    
    - name: VM from template
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      connection: local
      
      roles:
        - install
```

The issue is i don't know how to call vars from roles->vars directory as you can see in my playbook i have hard code variables. I need to get or set the variable in file and call it from that file.

```
**vcenter_hostname: vcenter-app
vcenter_user: john@doe
vcenter_pass: blabla6
esxhost: esx-4.cbalo.fr
datastore: VM-PROD-02-NORMAL
vmtemplate: Centos7-template
name: "newvm2"
datacenter: CD06
folder: Test**
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables in ansible are a set of values that will replace certain place-holders. You supply them when running your playbook and they will "trickle down" if you include roles etc. Check the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) to find out about variable precedence in ansible.

So what you want to do is to put your variable-assignments in your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) (you can split out variables in separate files as well, using `group_vars`) and then use the `-i path/to/inventory.yml` on your `ansible-playbook` command.

A structure could look like that:

```
my-ansible/
  roles/
    my-role/
      tasks/
        main.yaml
      defaults/
        main.yaml # contains default values for your variables
  inventory/
    inventory.yaml # contains hosts and variable assignments
  run.yaml
```

Then, you can run it like that:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yaml run.yaml
```

Hints:

- Don't use `my-role/vars` as it is very hard to override variable assignments in there. (See variable precedence)
- `defaults/main.yaml` is not necessary, but can be handy for variables you rarely change